# What is the SSRS 2012 equivalent of Crystal Reports XI Report Definition (TXT)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm using SSRS 2012 (Report Builder 3.0).

Does SSRS have an equivalent of the Crystal Reports export option of Report Definition (TXT)?

I have a report with many, many expressions.  I'd like to export them out, so I can check to see that I've done them correctly.  I'd rather not have to click into every single field.

Note: I don't have access to anything but the Report Builder, and all of our reporting is via cubes.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is an answer hence putting it as a comment: do you mean you want to see a text representation of the report definition? If you save the report itself to disk it lives as a .RDL file which includes everything about the report, which can be opened in a text editor.

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for this, but our reports are saved to SharePoint & I don't have the access the .RDL file.

Comment: If you have access to Report Builder where you can edit the report, you can 'Save As'.

Comment: Doh!  Thanks very much Rich.  That's solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED - Thanks to Rich.

For others that don't use the SSRS logo menu often:

- Click on the SSRS logo (top left - next to Save icon)
- Click on 'Save As' option

I could then save this file (out of SharePoint where it normally sits) onto my desktop and then open it with Notepad.